# min-cut with extra condition

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete

I have a undirected graph with no edge costs. A subset of the nodes are labeled $c_1, c_2, ..., c_k$ and one node is labeled $K$. I want to find the minimum cut of the graph with the extra condition that all nodes $c_i$ are in the same half of the cut and the node K is in the other cut.

My idea was to begin by doing a BFS from $K$ to all nodes $c_i$, saving predecessors and then finding all paths from $K$ to a node $c_i$ and finally picking the minimum set of edges from the paths so that at least one edge from each path was chosen. Unfortunately, if I understand this correctly, this is equivalent to the NP-complete [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Is there  anything sane with this approach? Do you have any hints to push me in the right direction?

Note: this is homework so I'd rather have some hints than a full solution.

Comment: Does this work? Turn your graph into a directed one, add vertex $C$ which is has an incoming edge from every $c_i$ with capacity $2m+1$, where $m$ is the number of edges of the old graph. Then compute a minimal flow, from $K$ to $C$.

Comment: Do you mean maximum flow <=> minimum cut? Because that's what I ended up doing and it seemed fine.

Comment: Yes, I think, the only thing you have to do is ensuring every minimal cut (in the sense of networks) separates all $c_i$  from $K$.

Comment: @frafl, your answer is correct, is better to turn your comment in an answer, also Zeta two, this isn't np-complete because max-flow mean cut is in $P$ (unless $P=NP$).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: ZetaTwo only wanted hints, so I thought he would like to answer himself. Also, I left out, where the cut is, but that's easily found on the web if it wasn't mentioned in his class.
ZetaTwo: Shall I answer or would you like to?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I didn't think the problem itself was NP but I managed to turn it into one by my bad path of reduction.

Comment: @frafl I have handed in my solution now which was based on what you said (though actually independently) so if you add the asnwer as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Another similar way would be to fuse (merge) all the nodes $c_i$ into a single node $C$ and then use flow from $K$ to $C$ to get the required cut. This is slightly more general as this works even when there are edge weights (and no  bound is known on the weights).

Comment: @polkjh: "no bound is known on the weights" - why do I need an a priori bound? If I get an input graph with maximal weight $w$, I just choose $2wm+1$ instead of $2m+1$.

Comment: @frafl: I meant, if you do not know the maximal weight (or any upper bound for it) in the graph ($w$ as you are assuming above).

Comment: @polkjh: If I consider a single input, i always know the maximal weight, since there are only finitely many weights. Or do you mean the weight can be $\infty$ for a certain edge. But than any minimum cut has to avoid them or every cut has infinite capacity if there is such an edge in every cut (and thus every cut is a minimum cut).

Comment: @frafl: The weights are finite but it is not known to you beforehand what the bound is. It is not that significant in this case, as you can always find it in $O(E)$ time by going through all the edges.

Comment: @polkjh: That's what I meant, when I said: "why do you need an **a priori** bound".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll use the **max-flow min-cut theorem** to solve this.

Therefore we map each instance $(G,K,\{c_{1},\dots,c_{k}\})$ to the network $N:=(V(G) \stackrel{.}{\cup} \{C\},E(N),e,K,C)$, where $C$ is a new vertex not in $V(G)$ (our sink), $K$ is our source and $e$ denotes the edge capacities,

$$E(N) := \{(u,v)|\{u,v\}\in E(G)\} \cup \{(c_i,C)|i\in\{1,\dots,k\}\}$$ and
$$e((u,v)) := \begin{cases}2|E(G)|+1&v=C\\1&\text{else} \end{cases}\qquad.$$

Then $(V_1,V_2)$ is a minimum $K$-$C$-cut in $N$ if and only if $(V_1,V_2\setminus\{C\})$ is  minimum cut in $G$ subject to the condition that $K\in V_1,\forall i: \, c_i\in V_2$:

"$\Rightarrow$": Every $K$-$C$-cut with the property $\forall i: \, c_i\in V_2$ has a capacity of at most $2E(G)$, every cut with $\exists i: \, c_i\in V_1$ has capacity of at least $2E(G)+1$. Therefore only those having the desired property can be a minimum cut. Since for each $(u,v), u\in V_1, v \in V_2$ of a minimum cut the edge capacity is $1$, $\mathrm{cap}(V_1,V_2)=||\{\{u,v\}\in E(G)|u\in V_1,v\in V_2\}||$.

"$\Leftarrow$": analogous to second part of "$\Rightarrow$".

If we have computed a maximum flow $f$ by e.g. the [Edmonds–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), we compute the residual Network $N_f$ where $e(N_f)=e-f$ and $E(N_f)=E(N)\setminus\{(u,v)|f((u,v))=1\}$, i.e. we remove the edges used by the maximum flow. Let $V_1$ be the set of vertices reachable from $K$ in $N_f$ and $V_2=V(G)\setminus V_1$. Then $(V_1,V_2\cup\{C\})$ is a minimum cut in $N$ and thus $(V_1.V_2)$ is a minimum cut in $G$ separating $K$ and $\{c_1,\dots,c_k\}$.